# XStream : node with attributes and text node?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I would like to serialize an object to an XML of this form with XStream.

```
<node att="value">text</node>
```

The value of the node (*text*) is a field on the serialized object, as well as the *att* attribute. Is this possible without writing a converter for this object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

write a convertor, it should be something similar to the code snippet

```
class FieldDtoConvertor implements Converter {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean canConvert(final Class clazz) {
        return clazz.equals(FieldDto.class);
    }

    public void marshal(final Object value,
            final HierarchicalStreamWriter writer,
            final MarshallingContext context) {
        final FieldDto fieldDto = (FieldDto) value;
        writer.addAttribute(fieldDto.getAttributeName(), fieldDto.getAttributeValue());     
    }
}
```

And while using XStream,register the convertor

```
final XStream stream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
stream.registerConverter(new FieldDtoConvertor());
```

Comment: yes, this looks like what I've done, but I've added a writer.setValue(fieldDto.getText()) to set the node's text.

Comment: yes Subb, it is required to set the node value, missed it in the snippet

Comment: look at @mantrid answer below. Thats the simpler way out.

Answer (score 19):

you can use a predefined Converter.

```
@XStreamAlias("node")
@XStreamConverter(value=ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings={"text"})
class Node {
  private String att;
  private String text;
}
```

[XStream Annotations Tutorial](http://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html) also says that for *att* attribute:

> Note, that no XStreamAsAttribute annotations were necessary. The
>   converter assumes it implicitly.

Comment: +1 This worked for me, although this is highly unintuitive. There should be an `@XStreamValue` annotation similar to JAXB's `@XmlValue` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier in JAXB

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Node {

    @XmlAttribute
    String att;

    @XmlValue
    String value;    

}
```

Comment: Check out my blog post comparing JAXB & XStream:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Comment: The question is about XStream, not JAXB.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of doing it:

```
   @XStreamAlias("My")
   private static class My {
      private String field;
   }

   XStream xStream = new XStream();
   xStream.autodetectAnnotations(true);
   xStream.useAttributeFor(My.class, "field");
```