# Mapping mixed content type using XStream

Tags: xstream

A question on creating java class for following XML node which contains a error code and description on the same element. My question is about how could I map the error message details in the java class so XStream works for deserializing.

XML:

```
<response code="failure">
   <![CDATA[error message details...]]>
</response>
```

Java:

```
@XStreamAlias("response")
public class ErrorResponse {
 @XStreamAlias("code")
    @XStreamAsAttribute
 private String code;  
....
....
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You may try this: http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-xstream-to-map-single-element.html Note this works only with Xstream 1.4.2 or above.

Answer (score 0):

The following may be what you are looking for:

- [XStream : node with attributes and text node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726863/xstream-node-with-attributes-and-text-node/3531214#3531214)

However, I'll point out what you are trying to do is much easier with JAXB:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="response")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ErrorResponse {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String code;

    @XmlValue
    private String description;

}
```